# DataGrid mouse double click event to populate data in Combo Box WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I would like to have the user a new window open and textboxes and combo boxes populate with the DataGrid row selected on the double click event. So far I was able to accomplish this with the textboxes but not the combo boxes. The combo boxes are shown as numeric values in the database and they point to another table for their items. With using `windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedIndex = windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Add(row["RPTTYPE"]);` I am able to show the numeric value in the new window but I'm not sure how to bind everything to display the text as it's done in `txt_UtilityRptTyp_Loaded`

This body of code populates the combo box with the table values from the SQL database

```
 public void txt_UtilityRptTyp_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter Status_data = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT RPTID, ReportType FROM [hb_RptType]", connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                Status_data.Fill(ds, "t");

                cmb_UtilityRptTyp.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["t"].DefaultView;
                cmb_UtilityRptTyp.DisplayMemberPath = "ReportType";
                cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedValuePath = "RPTID";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

This body of code shows the new window being open and the textboxes and combo boxes being populated with the values from the selected row.

```
 private void dtGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        // User double clicks on DataGrid Row
        // Open new Window
        // Populate selected textboxes with selected datarow
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        var windowToOpen = new Window1();

        if (gd != null)
        {
            // Textboxes
            windowToOpen.txt_RowRecrd.Text = row_selected["DSP_ID"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_acctnumber.Text = row_selected["ACCOUNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_analyst.Text = row_selected["TX_EMPLOYEE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_custname.Text = row_selected["CUST_NAME"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_address.Text = row_selected["PREM_ADDR"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Status.Text = row_selected["Status"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_opened.Text = row_selected["OPENED"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_deadline.Text = row_selected["DEADLINE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_revcls.Text = row_selected["RateType"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_WFMissuedBy.Text = row_selected["NM_USER"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_firstreview.Text = row_selected["FR_DT_FIRSTREV"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Latestupdate.Text = row_selected["FR_TS_LATESTUPD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_reviewNotes.Text = row_selected["FR_CMMNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_ResolutionNotes.Text = row_selected["COMMENT"].ToString();



            // ComboBoxes

            foreach (DataRowView row in dtGrid.SelectedItems)
            {
                windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Clear();
                windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedIndex = windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Add(row["RPTTYPE"]);
            }

            windowToOpen.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are you doing in `foreach loop` looks wrong. yo want to add all selected row items in `ComboBox` right ? and one of that item should be default `selected` in ComboBox ?

Comment: Each loop you see there are for textboxes the one at the bottom is for the one `ComboBox` that my I'm attempting to get right before including others  `windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedIndex = windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.Items.Add(row["RPTTYPE"]);` I just want to add the selected row where the column title is (RPTTYPE) to the `ComoBox`